# React Semantic UI - Transitions disappear again

Tags: reactjs, transition, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic UI React and have this `Transition.Group`

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({showBlogList: true}) }, 3500);
}
```

when mounting this is triggered

```
<Transition.Group animation='fade up' duration={2000}>
    {this.state.showBlogList && <Container id='blogPostList'>
    </Container>}
</Transition.Group>
```

The transition works fine but after fading it, it fades out again and is no longer visible.

This only happens on the fade transitions. All others work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me it was because of loading Bootstrap's CSS to the page, which have this rule:

```css
.fade:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Solved it by disabling that rule:

```css
.fade:not(.show){
    opacity: unset !important;
}
```